# Angular Material paginator nextPage property

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-material

I have a total of `250` items and I'm displaying `5` of them i.e. `pageSize` is set to 5.
and I've set the `paginator.length` property to `items.length`

Now, there are two problems here:

Even though I've manually set the `paginator.length` but when I `console.log` the properties of paginator, it shows `5` (Which is the number of items I'm displaying per page). hence the `next` button of paginator is disabled.

How do I enable the `next` button, so that when it is clicked I would know and request the next data to server.
Remember: I'm using only back-end pagination for this regard.
Pagination information is passed in response headers from the server.
Here is my code

```
pageIndex=1;
pageNumber;
pagination;
ngOnInit(): void {
    this.paginator.pageSize = 5;
    this.paginator.pageIndex = this.pageIndex;

    this.salesReportService.getDailyReport().subscribe((response) => {
      console.log('Response of sales report : ', response);
      this.reports = response.body;
      this.pagination=response.headers.get('X-Pagination');
      console.log('PaginationInformation: ',this.pagination)

      this.paginator.length=this.pagination.TotalCount;

      console.log('paginator properties: ', this.paginator);
      console.log('paginator hasNextpage(): ', this.paginator.hasNextPage());
      this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(this.reports);
      this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;
      this.dataSource.sort = this.sort;
    }, (error) => {
      console.log('Error occured while fetching sales report: ', error);
    });
  }
// here I'd call the function to get the next data when the next button of paginator is clicked.

// something like this
this.salesReportService.getReports(pageNumber:2)
```

Comment: I am facing same issue. Above answer did not help me. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66060058/angular-material-paginator-nextpage-is-disabled

Answer (score 2):

This is because you set paginator length in the first place and later trying to execute below lines

```
   this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(this.reports);
  this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;
```

which makes paginator to set length to data available in datasource.

So, after the above two lines keep the below line in your code.

```
  this.paginator.length=this.pagination.TotalCount; // this.paginator.length= 'No Of Records';
```

Hope it helps!